# How to display route in Google Street View?

Tags: google-maps, street-view

In the past, when you searched a route on Google Maps and then switched to Street View, the route was shown in the Street View image (as a thick blue line). That was a very useful feature, since it enabled one to follow the route in Street View, so that one was more likely to recognize important points when taking the route in the real world.

However now the route does not show up in Street View by default, and I couldn't find an option to show it.

Is there any way to display the route in Street View with the current interface?

And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Hmmm ... what exactly do you mean with "Earth View"? Anyway, I've now noticed that from my laptop, I get more or less the old interface; however also without the blue line in the picture. But unlike the new interface, I get at least the blue line in the card fragment in the corner, which is almost as good. With the new interface (which I get when using from my main computer), I don't see the blue line even in the card fragment. Unfortunately the fact that I get a different interface on my laptop means I cannot test anything until I'm back home.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no need for any 'adjustment' - at least for me it is 'automatic':

[image: Den Helder to Harlingen]

The above was achieved by selecting the route (by car) from Den Helder to Harlingen in Google Maps and then switching to Street View.